# Why Div Keeps expanding horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a big problem i was working on a chat system and designing the chat but i found i big problem which is my div is expanding horizontally and i want it to expand regular ( vertically ) and i tried alot of thing like clearfix and nothing happens !!!

```
<div class="nchat">
<img class="chatimg" src="img/attach_1.jpg">
<div class="chatcontent">Hi</div>
<div class="sendt"><img width="10" height="10" src="img/star.png"> 14:20</div>
</div>

.nchat {
min-height: 40px;
}
.sendt {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EFFFFF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #0099CC;
border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
border-right: 1px solid #0099CC;
border-top: 1px solid #0099CC;
color: #000000;
float: left;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 13px;
margin: 12px 0 0 -1px;
padding: 1px 3px;
}
.chatimg {
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
float: left;
height: 30px;
margin: 5px 10px;
width: 30px;
}
.chatcontent:before {
border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
border-right: 7px solid #0099CC;
border-top: 7px solid transparent;
content: "";
height: 0;
margin: 1.5px 0 0 -16px;
position: absolute;
width: 0;
}
.chatcontent {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099CC;
border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
color: #FFFFFF;
float: left;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 10px 0 0;
padding: 2px 5px 2px 10px;    
max-width: 180px;
}
```

Comment: Which div? Can you recreate this in JsFiddle.net ?

Comment: after doing what your div expands?

Comment: Probably because you never clear your float.  Using float breaks the natural flow of the elements.  Put a `clear: both;` before your chat content class.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `width` of the content you don't want to expand horizontally?

Comment: .chatcontent keeps expanding horizontally

Comment: how can i do it without float : left ???? 

i want it to be like this img / chat content / date

Comment: @Magikano check my answer ..i gave sample for both `word wrap`... and every `chat on next line`.
@Justin thanks for `clear:both`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SsqtE/1/)

I have changed the `.chatcontent`

```
.chatcontent {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099CC;
border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
color: #FFFFFF;
float: left;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 10px 0 0;
padding: 2px 5px 2px 10px;    
max-width: 180px;
clear: both;
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: ok change the message ( hi ) to any long message or just like this : eifjwijgiwgjowrgjoirjgorgjorwijg then see what happens it doesn't expand ( it doesn't make a new line ) !!!!

Comment: check updated answer The new link updated in answer. Let me know if you eed anything else? or accept as answer :D http://jsfiddle.net/SsqtE/1/

Comment: yeah it works ..... thanks very very much but i di it without clear : both only with word-wrap:break-word;

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to presume that the div in question is the `.nchat` div?

Have you tried setting either:

- Min and max widths on them.
- A fixed width

Plus everything is floated left - why have you done this? Surely a display:inline-block would just stack them all next to each other?

Comment: the div in question is .chatcontent

Comment: As Rehul Maindargi has answered this, I'll not continue on this. Thanks!